# Want to add color to a rectangle which i draw using openGL function

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, colors, cocos2d-iphone

I have to know how to add color to the rectangle drawn with the below method (which i took from a sample here).. Its by setting the openGL color to some color. But i dont know how to do it. Some help would be appreciated.

```
-(void) ccDrawFilledRect
{

HelloWorld *gs = [(swipeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]  gameScene];
CGPoint poli[]= {gs.StartPoint,CGPointMake(gs.StartPoint.x,gs.EndPoint.y),gs.EndPoint,CGPointMake(gs.EndPoint.x,gs.StartPoint.y)};

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, poli);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
NSLog(@"openGL rectangles drawn !!");

// restore default state
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Comment: em 2 serching for the same...

Comment: Hope some expert answers asap !

Comment: i also just started opengl . hav u any exp on cocos2d?

Comment: No, i am new to MAC itself.. I have worked on c++ and DirectX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NeHe has a lot of easy OpenGL tutorials. This one is on adding color http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=03 . Make your you have colors and color buffers enabled.

Have you tried putting `glColor3d(1, 0, 0)` before `glVertexPointer`?

Comment: Actually i did all correctly, i used glColor4d(R,G,B,A), but forgot to override the draw() function the main scene. Instead i called the openGL draw outside like other functions. I then overrode draw, and it works perfect now.. Thanks for reply